# Why would Flash work in IE 9 but not in IE 11?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, silverlight, internet-explorer

Why would Flash work in  IE 9 but not in IE 11?  That is, why would Adobe Flash work with Microsoft Internet Explorer Version 9 and not work with Microsoft Internet Explorer Version 11?

I am using a small flash object in the index page of www.gelsana.com. It appears on one computer using IE 9 but not on another computer using IE 11. I first thought it might be an issue with a virus, but I ran a couple of anti-virus programs and I still have the issue on the computer using IE 11. Any advice?

What I would prefer to do instead of just not showing the little flash object is post some sort of message instead telling the user to download this or that. But since the cause of it not showing, I guess, might be for several reasons, I would need some sort of browser sniffer. I mean, it does not show at all in Chrome or Firefox.

Can the problem be fixed with using a later version of flash?

It seems to me that every browser and every version should have some way to show Flash. Is this not the case?

The SWF file I am using in the index.html is:

http://www.gelsana.com/assets/site_map.swf

I am not the author if this file. If I need to rebuild it as a silverlight project, I will need to decompile it. Do the tools exist that will allow me to do this? Is it possible to first decompile a flash project and then convert it into silverlight?

I think the ugly truth is that Flash is dead or dying and everything needs to be redone in HTML5.  Say it isn't so.  I hope there is an easier solution.

Comment: Doesn't work in FF too

Answer (score 0):

Is ActiveX Filtering turned on? Check for a not symbol (circle with a slash) in the address bar and click it to turn it off if so.